# FBLoginView Button Tiling

Tags: ios, facebook, uiimageview, tiling

I have implemented `FBLoginView` on my previous version of my iOS app, suited for iOS 6&7. Recently, after the iOS 8 release, I upgraded my Facebook Framework to the latest version and below is the result of implementing the same `FBLoginView` button.

I tried using the previous version of the Facebook Framework, but I still experience the same problem.

Below is the implementation if the `FBLoginView` programmatically in my code

```
self.fbBtn = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
self.fbBtn.frame = CGRectZero;
self.fbBtn.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
self.fbBtn.delegate = [FacebookDelegateHelper sharedObject];
[self addSubview:self.fbBtn];
[self.fbBtn setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: FBloginView issue]

Comment: How you implement FBLoginView? Programmatically or Graphically?

Comment: the View is done programmatically so does the FBLoginView as edited question

Comment: Why do you set `self.fbBtn.frame = CGRectZero;`?

Comment: Im using `AutoresizingMask` for this `FBLoginView` button. Commenting this line won't make any difference and Im still getting the same result as in screenshot provided

Comment: have you tried comment this line `[self.fbBtn setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`

Comment: Yes I tried commenting the life and add a fixed size even with `CGRectMake` but I'm still unable to make it the way it should look like.

Comment: Yes, I did try every possible option and yet too solve the issue. I have temporary solved the issue by subclassing FBLoginView and custom making the way the button looks like. But still looking for a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The one that work would be:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);    // Your fbButton position
loginView.delegate = [FacebookDelegateHelper sharedObject];
[loginView siazeToFit];
[self addSubview:loginView];
```

This should make your button appear. Then the rest of your code could be in your delegate where `FBLoginViewDelegate` has been declared

There is an example named HelloFacebookSDK in FacebookSDK for your reference.

Comment: Nope, This doesn't work as well. I still have a tile of Facebook logo in my button as illustrated above